# Objective C: Compiler warning with enum

Tags: objective-c

In `myObject.h`:

```
typedef enum {
    GET,
    POST
} HTTPMethods;
```

And then inside the `@interface` definition, a property:

```
@property (nonatomic) HTTPMethods *httpMethod;
```

In `myClass.m`, I have the `#import` of `myObject.h` and then:

```
myObject *obj = [[myObject alloc] init];
obj.httpMethod = POST;
```

This seems to work, but the compiler yells at me:

```
`Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'HTTPMethods *' from 'int'.
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An enum is a built-in type, and not an object.  As such, you probably want to store the integral value itself and not a pointer.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) HTTPMethods httpMethod;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a big hint in the error message!

In C and Objective C, an enum is a user defined data type. You've written HTTPMethods *, which means "a pointer to an enum", whereas it looks like you just wanted an enum.

So change your property to this:

```
@property (nonatomic) HTTPMethods httpMethod;
```

For more info, google "C pointers" and you'll find information like this: http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm